# Connecting female thread to female threaded faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I am connecting a water filter to one of my taps. It’s driving me mad. The tap itself has an aerator that is readily unscrewed. The socket on the tap itself is female threaded. Here I am holding the aerator in my fingers and the tap is in the background.

[image]

The thread itself is inset a little bit into the tap.

My water filter connector is also female threaded.

[image]

So one of them must be converted to a male thread, and the adapter must be small enough not to cause a problem with the narrow space around the female connector that is slightly inset into the tap.

I googled a bit. I found e.g this [product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00400CPR2) decribed as a female to male adapter. But look at it! It goes into the female threaded connector and gives another female one!

What do I need to do the job and get my purifier connected?!

Comment: Confused - both items held in your fingers have male threads...

Comment: @innisfree - Also be aware that there are a bunch of different diameters and thread pitches used on faucets at the aerator attachment point.

Comment: The aerator in my fingers in the first picture has a male thread. The purifier in my hand in the second picture has a female thread.

Comment: The outside of the purifier connector is beveled but look closely it is female threaded

Comment: @innisfree - The picture in your question of the purifier that you are holding distinctly shows a male thread sticking out the top. Now unless you already have a male to male adapter already screwed into the purifier your picture is creating nothing but confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I know little about these things, but eg the aerator in my hand in the first picture can screw INTO the purifier connector. Doesn’t that make the aerator male and the purifier connector female?

Comment: Not every tap has a standard aerator, and I have had to change taps to fit filters and the like.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It’s not a shopping question - the crux of it was my confusion about the naming convention a special part that I needed

Answer (score 2):

If we can believe what you wrote in your question rather than what you show in your pictures then what you are really looking for is a M to M adapter. Not the F to M adapter that you linked. Here is an example of an M to M adapter.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: [https://www.amazon.com/Danco-10524-Chrome-Aerator-Adapter/dp/B00FI6U81C/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=male+to+male+faucet+adapter&qid=1552209508&s=gateway&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FI6U81C))*</sup>

There are multiple sizes used for aerator attachments. Some of the most common include in metric sizes M22x1, M24x1 and M28x1. In USA sizes you will find 3/4"-27, 15/16"-27 and 55/64"-27. The first number being the diameter and the second the thread pitch designation. So take this into account when you select the proper adapter. Some adapters are actually designed to convert between these sizes including the one that you linked in your question.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. My confusion was that I would call the item you picture F to M since it converts a F faucet into a M one or vice-versa :)

Comment: Just curious -- a 15/16" male requires a 15/16" female (and vica versa), while a 55/64" male requires a 55/64" female (and vica versa), is that correct?

Comment: No. Not correct. Adapter whether the be M-M, F-F, M-F or M-F could and do often have different diameters / thread pitch on their oposite sides.